Issues with a Docker container in a Synology setup starting and configuring
I'm trying to install a Docker extension; that extension being IMAPSync. Although I'm using Container Manager which is an app in Synology NAS system.
I've read the documentation numerous times for the container. Although I cannot get the extension to work. In particular with regard to the compose file which is returning a bind error which is specific to this container ?
 imapsync:
    container_name: imapsync
    ports: 
    - 12580:8080 
    restart: unless-stopped
    image: gilleslamiral/imapsync
    volumes:
        - /usr/bin/imapsync/imapsync_form_extra.html:/var/tmp/imapsync_form_extra.html \
        - /usr/bin/imapsync_cgi:/var/tmp/imapsync_cgi  \

From my understand it's due to the paths are incorrect; I always forget what the colon means in the volume path.
The other issue with the container is this HTML file, where is it located on my NAS, and how do I get it to load ?
